# ORACLE SQL: Slow query when using "join table on id = id" vs "where id = number"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having performance problem in a querie when I use a subquery to set an ID = number, and then join that subquery in the main query to look for that ID, this method takes about 150 seconds. But if I delete the subquery and look for the ID = number directly in the main query, it takes 0,5 second.

Here some code as exemple:
This is the example of 150 seconds
In this I set the cto_in_codigo in the With clause.

```
WITH CONTRATOS AS (
  SELECT CTO_IN_CODIGO FROM MGCAR.CAR_CONTRATO
  WHERE CTO_IN_CODIGO = 14393
)

SELECT
    PT.PAR_IN_CODIGO,
    PTC.PARCOR_IN_INDICE

  FROM (
      SELECT
        MAX(PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO) OVER (PARTITION BY PT.PAR_IN_CODIGO, PT.CTO_IN_CODIGO) HPAR_IN_CODIGO_MAX,
        PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO,
        PT.CTO_IN_CODIGO,
        PT.PAR_IN_CODIGO

      FROM
        QUERIE.PARCELA_TOTAL PT
        JOIN CONTRATOS CTO
          ON CTO.CTO_IN_CODIGO = PT.CTO_IN_CODIGO

      WHERE
        PT.PAR_DT_REAJUSTE <= TO_DATE('31/12/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')


    ) PT
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
        MAX(PTC.PARCOR_IN_CODIGO) OVER (PARTITION BY PTC.PAR_IN_CODIGO, PTC.CTO_IN_CODIGO) PARCOR_IN_CODIGO_MAX,
        PTC.PARCOR_IN_CODIGO,
        PTC.CTO_IN_CODIGO,
        PTC.PAR_IN_CODIGO,
        PTC.HPAR_IN_CODIGO,
        PTC.PARCOR_IN_INDICE

      FROM
        QUERIE.PARCELA_TOTAL_CORRECAO PTC
        JOIN CONTRATOS CTO
          ON CTO.CTO_IN_CODIGO = PTC.CTO_IN_CODIGO

    ) PTC
    ON PTC.CTO_IN_CODIGO = PT.CTO_IN_CODIGO
    AND PTC.PAR_IN_CODIGO = PT.PAR_IN_CODIGO
    AND PTC.HPAR_IN_CODIGO = PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO
    AND PTC.PARCOR_IN_CODIGO = PTC.PARCOR_IN_CODIGO_MAX

  WHERE
    PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO = PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO_MAX
```

and this is the 0,5 sec.
in this I set the cto_in_codigo inside each query

```
SELECT
    PT.PAR_IN_CODIGO,
    PTC.PARCOR_IN_INDICE

  FROM (
      SELECT
        MAX(PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO) OVER (PARTITION BY PT.PAR_IN_CODIGO, PT.CTO_IN_CODIGO) HPAR_IN_CODIGO_MAX,
        PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO,
        PT.CTO_IN_CODIGO,
        PT.PAR_IN_CODIGO

      FROM
        QUERIE.PARCELA_TOTAL PT

      WHERE
        PT.PAR_DT_REAJUSTE <= TO_DATE('31/12/2017', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
        AND PT.CTO_IN_CODIGO = 14393

    ) PT
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT
        MAX(PTC.PARCOR_IN_CODIGO) OVER (PARTITION BY PTC.PAR_IN_CODIGO, PTC.CTO_IN_CODIGO) PARCOR_IN_CODIGO_MAX,
        PTC.PARCOR_IN_CODIGO,
        PTC.CTO_IN_CODIGO,
        PTC.PAR_IN_CODIGO,
        PTC.HPAR_IN_CODIGO,
        PTC.PARCOR_IN_INDICE

      FROM
        QUERIE.PARCELA_TOTAL_CORRECAO PTC

      WHERE
        PTC.CTO_IN_CODIGO = 14393

    ) PTC
    ON PTC.CTO_IN_CODIGO = PT.CTO_IN_CODIGO
    AND PTC.PAR_IN_CODIGO = PT.PAR_IN_CODIGO
    AND PTC.HPAR_IN_CODIGO = PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO
    AND PTC.PARCOR_IN_CODIGO = PTC.PARCOR_IN_CODIGO_MAX

  WHERE
    PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO = PT.HPAR_IN_CODIGO_MAX
```

what is confusing to me is that the with clause returns just one row with the cto_in_codigo number, much like if I hard code then inside each query like the second code. What is could be causing this super delay?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plans. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Why is that? just to know what is in those tables? You can supose that the mgcar.car_contrato have only cto_in_codigo as column, and about 16k rows of data. Knowing that do not change anything in the question above, as what I asked is why is it diferent in performance to do a join with an 1 row query than put the result of that row in the where clause.

Comment: Execution plans should be the first thing *you* should check, so it should not be a big deal to share them.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database?answertab=active#tab-top) some hints. Also a good practice is to simplify the examples, leaving out parts so, that the problem remains. There is a good chance that doing so *you* identifies the problem.